# Adding splash effect on top of custom widget

Tags: flutter

I have the following widget:

```dart
class _BuildingItem extends StatelessWidget {

  final String address;
  final String zip;
  final String zipCityName;
  final Image image;

  const _BuildingItem({Key? key,
    required this.address,
    required this.zip,
    required this.zipCityName,
    required this.image
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ClipRect(
              child: image,
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child: DefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                    child: Text(
                        this.address
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5.0),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                              this.zip + ", "
                          ),
                          Text(
                              this.zipCityName
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I wish to add a splash effect on top of this widget. Wrapping the widget in an InkWell does not work as I want, as it puts the splash effect on the parent widget. I might have stared myself blind at this, but how should I "merge" an InkWell inside this widget to get the splash effect to render on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by putting the widget inside a stack and adding a Material and InkWell widget as the second child of that stack (so that the InkWell and Material widgets are put on top of the original custom widget).